# Installed sqlite3 v3.8, but mac terminal still runs old version 3.6 by default

Tags: path, sqlite

I have a Mac running OS X 10.6.8, which comes pre-installed with SQLite3 v3.6.  I installed v3.8 using homebrew.  But when I type "sqlite3" in my terminal it continues to run the old pre-installed version.  Any help?

Not sure if PATH variable has anything to do with it, but running echo $PATH results in the following:
/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

And the NEW version of SQLite3 is in the following directory:
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite

I should add that I also downloaded the binary executable to my desktop, and that works if I click from my desktop, but doesn't work from the terminal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### $PATH

Yes you need to set your `PATH` variable like so:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

That line can be a bit tricky to read so here it is split up by the colons, and each path is on its own line:

```
$ awk -v addPath="$1" 'BEGIN{RS=":";ORS=addPath "\n"}{$1=$1}1' <<< $PATH
/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite
/usr/local/bin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/X11/bin
```

The `$PATH` is a list of directories - separated by colons (`:`) - which the shell searches through one by one looking for what ever you just typed at the prompt. The order matters so if `sqlite` shows up in multiple locations the first directory where it's found is where it will get used from.

#### where are things located?

You can use the `type` command to see where a particular application is coming from.

#### Examples

```
$ type -a sqlite3 
sqlite3 is /usr/bin/sqlite3
```

Here's I'm using it with the `-a` switch which will show all occurrences:

```
$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /bin/ls
```

Comment: That worked!  Thank you so much. I didn't know how to add multiple paths into the statement.  Now it's clear they're just separated by ":"

Comment: @user46531 - glad your issue was resolved. Thanks for the question.

Comment: @user46531 while workable, this is the incorrect solution. see my answer.

Answer (score 12):

slm's solution is actually incorrect (while usable). When using Homebrew you should not add `/usr/local/Cellar/*` into your $PATH; instead what you should do is you should add `/usr/local/bin` into your $PATH (which you have already done) and then symlink things in the Cellar into `/usr/local/bin`. Since it's designed this way, Homebrew can obviously do this pretty easily for you:

```
brew link sqlite
```

will automagically create the needed links. (Homebrew didn't do this automatically for you this time because sqlite is keg-only, meaning that you need to do it manually).

As a side note/friendly reminder, you should never add `/usr/local/bin` to the system path, only your user path. This is in case programs expect the Apple-provided sqlite but find the Homebrew-provided version, causing problems.

Comment: Possibly not a good idea. brew link sqlite: "Warning: sqlite is keg-only and must be linked with --force"

Comment: Yeah—what are the negative consequences (if any) of linking it forcibly?  What could break?  They really should give some indication of that in the warning message.